# Sticky columns for dynamic colum definition

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to define an Angular Material table with approx 24 columns and they are not uniform in behavior. Some columns just display text, others may have controls. I want to try and keep it as dynamic as possible and not have them all defined in the HTML file.

I have created an object to define a column object and create the columns dynamically:

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columnDefinitions" [matColumnDef]="column.columnName">
            <th mat-header-cell
                *matHeaderCellDef
                mat-sort-header
                [disabled]="!column.sortable"> {{ column.label }} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"
            [ngClass]="getClasses(row, column)"> {{ getColumnContentFor(row, column.columnPath) }} </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Some of the questions I have are around how to best add functionality based on the type of column I need:

1. I want to add a sticky column just to the first couple of columns
2. Ideally even the [ngClass] would like it only for certain columns so it doesn't have to evaluate this function for every column.
3. If some columns have a custom control how can I add a custom template

Any examples you may suggest would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do this by adding the index to ngFor, like this: `*ngFor="let column of columnDefinitions; let i = index"`. Then, you can conditionally add the sticky position by adding this to the `th` cell: `[style.position]="i < 2 ? 'sticky' : null"` (null value means that the style won't be added).
   **EDIT**: You also need to change the matHeaderRowDef to `*matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky: true"`
2. While you can use something like ngSwitch for that, I don't think it's worth the effort. You can, however, make sure you return null as early as possible for classes that don't need it.
3. Inside the `td` element, you can use ngSwitch, as described [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase). You can use the column index, for example.

[image: Sticky first two columns]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying your suggestion for point 1 and it doesn't seem to work. Is there something I am missing? Just to clarify I also have a sticky column header. I tried setting just one sticky column and it still didn't work.

Comment: If you can have an example in CodeSandbox (or similar) it would be easier to help

Comment: Please let me know if you can't see this ok: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vucpbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.html)

Comment: @ancamc Not sure if it saved that, but see my edit to 1 - afterwards it seems to work

Comment: I have saved the code sample on Stackblitz with your edit suggestion but I still do not see the first two columns locked in. It was working ok for you?

Comment: @ancamc yes (after I fix the tiny typo you have)

Comment: Oh yes I found the typo, thank you for mentioning it. I have updated the code with my original intended result. Thank you for the guidance.